# I never {drunk / drank}

Tags: verb-forms

While talking with my friend, I came to an awkward sentence:

> I never drunk.

Is it right? I think *drank* should come. I'd like to know what form of verb should be used with *never*?

Comment: Or *I **am** never drunk*.

Answer (score 10):

Insertion of *never* doesn't change the choice of form in this case:

> I drank.
> I *never* drank.

The same is true for other forms of *drink*.  Compare:

> I drink coffee.
> I *never* drink coffee.
>
> I have drunk coffee.
> I have *never* drunk coffee.

*Drink* is a bit of an odd word, historically.  For a time, it was fashionable to avoid association with drunkenness by saying *drank* when *drunk* was more appropriate.  In today's English, this is considered non-standard, and you should avoid making this error yourself--but in some dialects (such as mine!) the form *have drank* is still preferred, so you may come across it once in a while.

Comment: Also see slang nouns *[drank](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drank#Noun)* and *[purple drank](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/purple_drank)*

Comment: If we are speaking about alcohol, for me there is a difference between saying, "I never drank" and "I have never been drunk". The first implies you have never had a sip of alcohol in your life, and in the second, you can say you have had alcohol, but you have never been in a state of drunkenness.

Comment: @TrishRempel That's a good point.  I feel this is best explained by saying there are [two words spelled "drunk"](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/drunk): one is the past participle of "to drink", and the other is an adjective *derived from* the past participle.  This adjective has taken on a new meaning ("strongly intoxicated").  "Drunken" is another form of this adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm adding anything very useful here but

> I never drunk

might be heard in certain English accents in certain parts of the world. Here are two examples:

- [Ulster Scots (pdf)](http://www.dcalni.gov.uk/ulster-scots-glossary.pdf)
- [Southern America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English) (if you believe Wikipedia)

So it wouldn't be appropriate in a job interview in London (for all kinds of reasons) but you might use it if you wanted to sound natural in a pub in Belfast :-).

Answer (score 0):

People are now starting to say "I never drunk."

This sounds wrong to me. However *language is defined by its usage*, so if enough people say, "I never drunk," then "I never drunk" it is, like it or not :-(

Answer (score 0):

You would say "**drank**" because it is the past tense, which is the way it should be said for this sentence. That is, if I'm reading the context correctly.
"**Drunk**" is the past participle- which you *could* use, but not when saying **

> "I never drunk"

**. You could use past participle if you put in a "had" or a "have".
In short,

> "I never drank"

would be correct.
For more information, see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37208/when-to-use-drank-and-drunk).