# Do multiple verbs need to be gerund?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

I've got dummy examples below :

> - You use this tool to cut, break, and repair the box.

or is it

> - You use this tool to cut, breaking, and repairing the box.

Also the following cases where there is a preposition in front of the previous verb.

> - She is good at singing, dance , and study.

or  is it

> - She is good at singing, dancing , and studying.

I have 2 questions :

1). Do they need to be gerund.

2). Whether or not they need to be, do the following verbs should be in form of the previous verbs' sentence? like :

> - She came, drank, and slept.

also

> - She  was eating, drinking, and talking at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [“drank” and “drunk”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37208/). As it stands, your example means *She arrived **in a state of intoxication,** then went to sleep*. And your second "tool" example is either ungrammatical or it's a clumsy way of implying that breaking and repairing the box are "side effects, consequences" of using the tool to cut.

Comment: my mistake drunk is perfect form

Comment: In your first quote, the tool is used to do 3 things. In the second, it does one thing (cut) that results in two consequences for the box.

Answer (score 1):

The following verbs do not need to be in the form of the previous verbs' sentence, **but they should be to add clarity to your writing.** This is known as parallelism. Parallel structure (also called parallelism) is the repetition of a chosen grammatical form within a sentence.

**They do not need to be a gerund, they can almost any part of speech.**

For example:

These have parallel structure:

> I like *hiking*, *biking*, and *swimming*. (These are all gerunds.)
>
> Mary wanted to make sure that she made her presentation *creatively*, *effectively* and *persuasively*. (These are all adverbs.)
>
> My mom criticized public schools because they *require* students to attend, *receive* money from the government, and *destroy* students' humanity. (These are all verbs.)

_

Yet, these do not have parallel structure.

> I *hiked*, *bike* and *swam*. (Notice the first and third actions are past tense, but the second action is a present.)
>
> Dogs are great pets for the following reasons: they are *loyal*, they are *loving*, and because of their *obedience*. (First and second traits are adjectives, but third trait is a noun.)
>
> People who get ahead do lots of different things such as: *attend college*, *studying*, and *working hard*. (Second and third are gerunds, yet first is a participle.)

It becomes tremendously awkward to read: so the best thing you should do is to make all three actions *the same part of speech and the same tense*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just want to emphasise that parallelism is a matter of style. Lacking parallelism doesn't make a structure incorrect - only makes sentences harder to read.